# hardlinks in Linux

Tags: linux, hardlink

What is the size of the `hardlink` in `Linux`? Will it be the size of the `inode`? If I have two of them?

Thanks in advnace for any explanation, I tried to `google` it, but didn't find anything

Comment: Is this a programming question? Shouldn't it be posted in http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hard link reuses the *inode*, but requires a separate directory entry, which takes up [8 bytes plus the length of the file name](http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html#LINKED-DIRECTORIES) in ext2. There may be other costs associated, such as when directory indexing is used, also, directories grow by entire blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Think of a hard link as just another name for a file. If a file has 1000 hard links, that just means that it has 1000 different directory entries associated with it, all with potentially different names. For example, if you had 1000 different names, you would still only be one person. You'd take up the same amount of space no matter how many names you had. You'd just have a bit more paperwork for each additional name.